# Conditional expectation and sum of random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-probability

Let $Y, X_1, . . . , X_n$ be continuous random variables (not necessarily independent) with non negative range, i.e. $P(Y < 0) = 0$ and $P(X_i < 0) = 0$ for $i = 1 \ldots n$, verifying the following property concerning the conditional expectation:

(1) $E[Y | X_1 + ... + X_n = u] \geq E[Y | X_1 + ... + X_n = v]$

for arbitrary positive reals $u \geq v$. Is there anyone who is able to prove that (1) implies

(2) $E[Y | X_1 = w] \geq E[Y | X_1 = z]$

for arbitrary positive reals $w \geq z$ ? Also a counterexample which prove that this is not always the case would be welcome.

Comment: How does it feel to completely modify your question *after* some answers got posted? And to choose new notations which make obsolete those used in some answers? Would you say such a behaviour is (1.) nice, (2.) so-so, (3.) a disaster?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=X_2+X_3+X_4$. Here is a counterexample:

Let $X_1=-X_2=X_3=X_4$. Then $E[X_1\mid Y]=Y$ is an increasing function of $Y$ while $E[X_1\mid X_2]=-X_2$ is a decreasing function of $X_2$.

If the random variables must be positive, let $X_1=X_3=X_4$ with values in some bounded positive interval $(0,c)$ and $X_2=c-X_1$. Then $E[X_1\mid Y]=Y-c$ is an increasing function of $Y$  while $E[X_1\mid X_2]=c-X_2$ is a decreasing function of $X_2$.

---

(*Due to vandalism by the OP, the question that this answer addresses is now impossible to guess. We reproduce it here, correcting some typos, grammar errors and awkward formulations.*)

> Let X1, X2, X3, X4 be continuous random variables (not necessarily independent) verifying the following property concerning the conditional expectation:
>
> (1) E(X1 | X2 + X3 + X4 = u) ≥ E(X1 | X2 + X3 + X4 = v)
>
> for arbitrary positive reals u ≥ v. Can one prove that (1) implies
>
> (2) E(X1 | X2 = w) ≥ E(X1 | X2 = z)
>
> for arbitrary positive reals w ≥ z ? Counterexamples proving that this is not always the case would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Let $X_3$ be a random variable that satisfies $E[X_1|X_3 = u] \geq E[X_1|X_3 = v]$ whenever $u \geq v$. Let $X_2$ be a random variable that does not satisfy $E[X_1|X_2 = u] \geq E[X_1|X_2 = v]$ whenever $u \geq v$. Let $X_4 = -X_2$.

Comment: Perhaps if we add a requirement that forces X1, X2, X3, X4 to be non negative the implication can be proved.

Comment: What I understood of your counterexample is that we might have conditional expectations which do not verify E[X1 | Xi = w] >= E[X1 | Xi = z] and at the same time they verify E[X1 | X1+...+Xn = u] >= E[X1 | Xi = v]

Comment: @StefanoNasini Yes.